# Why can't Go compiler deduce that a struct implements an interface

Tags: go, interface

Running the code below will result in a compilation error:

> cannot use authors (type []Person) as type []Namer in return argument

Why can't Go compile it?

```
type Namer interface {
    Name() string
}

type Person struct {
    name string
}

func (r Person) Name() string {
    return r.name
}

func Authors() []Namer {
    // One or the other is used - both are not good:
    authors := make([]Person, 10)
    var authors []Person

    ...

    return authors
```

Declaring `authors` as `authors := make([]Namer, 10)` or `var authors []Namer` would be fine, but I can't see why the compiler cannot infer that `Person` is `Namer`.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Comment: `Person` isn't `Namer`. They are different types. It's true that `Person` implements the `Namer` interface, but that only means that a value of `Person` is assignable to a value of type `Namer`. It has doesn't have any general implications about type equivalence, for example in composite types as you're showing here. That is why deep conversion is required (see Cerise's comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a `[]Person` *is not* a `[]Namer`. Let's take your example one step further:

```
type Namer interface {
    Name() string
}

type Person struct {
    name string
}

func (r Person) Name() string {
    return r.name
}

type Thing struct {
    name string
}

func (t Thing) Name() string {
    return r.name
}

func Authors() []Namer {
    authors := make([]Person, 10)
    return authors
}

func main() {
    namers := Authors()
    // Great! This gives me a []Namer, according to the return type, I'll use it that way!
    thing := Thing{}
    namers := append(namers, thing)
    // This *should* work, because it's supposed to be a []Namer, and Thing is a Namer.
    // But you can't put a Thing in a []Person, because that's a concrete type.
}
```

If code expects to receive a `[]Namer`, that is what it *must* get. Not `[]ConcreteTypeThatImplementsNamer` - they're not interchangeable.